# difference beetween switch and if else statement

Tags: c, if-statement, switch-statement

I was struggling with if else statements and decided to try same with switch statement and for some reason it happened to work and now my program works like it should.. But it left me to wonder what is different beetween these 2 codes.. In my eyes both of them should work but for some reason not..

if:

```
   if (nibbleState = UNPACK_WAIT_FOR_1ST_NIBBLE)
    {
        if ((code = isUnPackedItem(nb)) == UNPACKED_ITEM)
        {
            nibbleState = UNPACK_WAIT_FOR_2ND_NIBBLE;
        }
        else
        {
            putc(code, fpOut);
            ++byteOutCnt;
        }
    }
    else if (nibbleState = UNPACK_WAIT_FOR_2ND_NIBBLE)
    {
        nibbleState = nb;
        nibbleState = UNPACK_WAIT_FOR_3RD_NIBBLE;
    }
    else if (nibbleState = UNPACK_WAIT_FOR_3RD_NIBBLE)
    {
        nibbleLow = nb;
        putc((nibbleMid << 4 | nibbleLow, fpOut);
        nibbleState = UNPACK_WAIT_FOR_1ST_NIBBLE;
        ++byteOutCnt;
    }
```

Switch:

```
switch (nibbleState)
    {
    case UNPACK_WAIT_FOR_1ST_NIBBLE:
        if ((code = isUnPackedItem(nb)) == UNPACKED_ITEM)
        {

            nibbleState = UNPACK_WAIT_FOR_2ND_NIBBLE;
        }
        else
        {
            putc(code, fpOut);
            ++byteOutCnt;
        }
        break;
    case UNPACK_WAIT_FOR_2ND_NIBBLE:
        nibbleMid = nb;
        nibbleState = UNPACK_WAIT_FOR_3RD_NIBBLE;
        break;
    case UNPACK_WAIT_FOR_3RD_NIBBLE:
        nibbleLow = nb;
        putc((nibbleMid << 4) | nibbleLow, fpOut);
        nibbleState = UNPACK_WAIT_FOR_1ST_NIBBLE;
        ++byteOutCnt;
        break;
    }
```

Comment: Did you mean `==` in those `else if`s and the first `if`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While checking the condition in the if statement, we have to check that the condition is equal using the `==` operator.
But you are assigning the value of `UNPACK_WAIT_FOR_1ST_NIBBLE` to `nibbleState`.
This is not a condition. You have to check the condition as

```
         if (nibbleState == UNPACK_WAIT_FOR_1ST_NIBBLE) //condition to check whether both are equal.
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 if (nibbleState = UNPACK_WAIT_FOR_1ST_NIBBLE)
```

should be

```
 if (nibbleState == UNPACK_WAIT_FOR_1ST_NIBBLE)
```

The same goes for the rest of the checks. Turning on the warnings , compiler should you warn you about this piece of code.

Answer (score 0):

You are assigning the value to that variable it will always true when the value is non zero.
 change the condition into like this.

```
if (nibbleState == UNPACK_WAIT_FOR_1ST_NIBBLE)
```

While doing the assignation, you are doing like this, `nibbleState=UNPACK_WAIT_FOR_1ST_NIBBLE` So the value of `UNPACK_WAIT_FOR_1ST_NIBBLE` will assign to that variable. If the value of this variable `UNPACK_WAIT_FOR_1ST_NIBBLE` is non zero then that first condition will always true. so it will not check other things.

Answer (score 0):

switch has direct memory jumps whereas if else has linked jumps in your byte code.

if else is more slower than switch case

for your [reference.](http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?SwitchStatement)

Answer (score 0):

As the above stated, you are assigning a value to nibbleState (=) when you should be checking the condition (==).

Additionally, I noticed that in your second condition check, you are doubly assigning a value to the same variable (overwriting the first assignment).

```
else if (nibbleState = UNPACK_WAIT_FOR_2ND_NIBBLE)
{
    nibbleState = nb; // <<  This value gets overwritten by the next line
    nibbleState = UNPACK_WAIT_FOR_3RD_NIBBLE;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem in case of your `if..else` condition usage is, instead of checking for the equality using `==` operator, you've used the assignment operator `=`.

> **Expected behaviour**

Check the value of `nibbleState` against the defined value<sup>#</sup>. `if` condition yields *TRUE* **if the values are equal**.

> **Actual Behaviour**

*Assign* the defined value to `nibbleState`. If the defined value in *non-zero*, `if` condition yields *TRUE*.

Suggestion: Enable compilar flags to warn you of the potential pitfall like this. Use of `-Wparentheses` or `-Wall` with `gcc` [produces a warning](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Warning-Options.html#index-Wparentheses-344) in the above cases, like

> warning: suggest parentheses around assignment used as truth value

---

<sup># -> `UNPACK_WAIT_FOR_<n.th>_NIBBLE`</sup>